# while using .namespace_map, in the output xml it is adding url as an attribute at the end of tag where ever that prefix is used

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, python-2.6

xml file which is processed:

```
<?xml version = "2.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:Version = "2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.0" xmlns:foo.a ="http://example.com/mphg/" xmlns:foo.b = "http://example.com/abcd/">
<foo.a:city name = "DELHI"></foo.a:city>
<foo.b:city name = "ChandiniChouk"></foo.b:city>
</xmi:XMI>
```

code for xml processing using python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys, os

ET._namespace_map["http://example.com/mphg/"] ="foo.a"
ET._namespace_map["http://example.com/abcd/"] = "foo.b"

tree = ET.parse(web.xml)
root = tree.getroot()
tree.write(file, encoding = "UTF-8", xml_declaration = True)
```

OUTPUT xml file

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:Version = "2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.0">
<foo.a:city name = "DELHI" xmlns:foo.a ="http://example.com/mphg/" ></foo.a:city>
<foo.b:city name = "ChandiniChouk" xmlns:foo.b = "http://example.com/abcd/"></foo.b:city>
</xmi:XMI>
```

the file is added with extra attribute which is not required and also all the namespaces are getting removed from the root tag

Comment: Please start by making your input document well-formed. There is no declaration for the `xmi` prefix (I pointed out the same thing here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54025003/407651).

Comment: Kindly update question.. I am not getting what you want to convey....please attach any solution for this problem statement...Thank you

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Comment: it is  python 2.6.6